# Can we prove the difference of phase between the voltage of three alternating current is 120 degree with "math formula"?

Tags: voltage, three-phase

In the three-phase electric power,we will assume the difference of phase  between the voltage of three alternating current is 120 degree

I want to ask why do we assume the 120 degree is the best option for the difference of three voltage phase?Can it be proved with math formula ?

Comment: They're evenly spaced which makes it better for most applications. 3 x 120° = ?

Comment: Define what "best option" means to you.

Comment: @DaveTweed If 120 degree is not the best option,why don't we use like 90 degree,45 degree? the best option means this

Comment: @SpehroPefhany 360 degree is like a circle,but why do we want to let  the degree become \$\frac{3}{360}\$? why don't we assume the degree become \$\frac{3}{90}\$ or \$\frac{3}{180}\$?

Comment: Not generally. If you're allowed to assume an ideal system, yes, but unbalanced loads on different phases will modify that phase difference; in the real world, 120 degrees is an approximation not an exact value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the three-phase electric power, we will assume the difference of phase between the voltage of three alternating current is 120 degree.

No, the phase relationship is not assumed, it is *designed*.

[image]

*Figure 1. Source: [TES](https://www.tes.com/lessons/nluZEBIrM933_w/three-phase-system). (Original author unknown.)*

As shown in Figure 1, the poles are mechanically laid out in a 120° spacing so the voltage outputs are offset by 120°.

> I want to ask why do we assume the 120 degree is the best option for the difference of three voltage phase? Can it be proved with math formula ?

The maths should be fairly straight forward. The three phases balance out when set at 120°. If you can prove that \$ sin(a) + sin(a - \frac {2}{3}\pi) + sin(a - \frac {4}{3}\pi) = 0 \$ you will have shown that the phases are perfectly balanced for all values of *a*. Thus the current in on any one phase is perfectly balanced by the current out on the other two. (Hence we don't require a neutral connection for a balanced load.)

Comment: @shineele, thank you for accepting my answer but I recommend that you unaccept for a day or two to give the whole of humanity - some of who are asleep right now - a chance to answer. Different answers may give you different ways of looking at the matter which will help you further.

Comment: It's also worth emphasizing that the net magnetic field produced by cables feeding a balanced load from a balanced supply (120 deg spacing) is zero. If the angles were not so then all havoc would happen when laying cables near to other wiring. +1 on the neat gif.